# Rust member functions as multithreaded mutable callbacks in real-time safe code

Tags: multithreading, audio, rust, callback

I am looking to use a member function of a struct as a mutable callback. The standard way I would do this is by wrapping my struct instance in a [mutex](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Mutex.html) and then in an [Arc](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Arc.html#method.get_mut). In this use case however, my callback is a real-time audio callback which needs to be real-time safe and is triggered on a dedicated thread. This means no locking can happen that might delay the callback from occurring.

My actual member callback method must take a mutable reference to the struct (I think this is where things fall apart). The struct does contain members but these can all be atomic variables.

Here is an example of the kind of thing I'm looking for:

```
use std::sync::Arc;
use clap::error;
use cpal::{traits::{HostTrait, DeviceTrait}, StreamConfig, OutputCallbackInfo, StreamError};
use std::sync::atomic::AtomicI16;

pub struct AudioProcessor {
     var: AtomicI16,
}

impl AudioProcessor {
    fn audio_block_f32(&mut self, audio: &mut [f32], _info: &OutputCallbackInfo) {
    }

    fn audio_error(&mut self, error: StreamError) {
    }
}

fn initAudio()
{
     let out_dev = cpal::default_host().default_output_device().expect("No available output device found");

     let mut supported_configs_range = out_dev.supported_output_configs().expect("Could not obtain device configs");
     let config = supported_configs_range.next().expect("No available configs").with_max_sample_rate();

     let proc = Arc::new(AudioProcessor{var: AtomicI16::new(5)});
     let audio_callback_instance = proc.clone();
     let error_callback_instance = proc.clone();

     out_dev.build_output_stream(&StreamConfig::from(config), move |audio: &mut [f32], info: &OutputCallbackInfo| audio_callback_instance.audio_block_f32(audio, info), move |stream_error| error_callback_instance.clone().audio_error(stream_error));
 }
```

Currently this code fails in the build_output_stream() function with this error message:

> cannot borrow data in an `Arc` as mutable
> trait `DerefMut` is required to modify through a dereference, but it is not implemented for `Arc<AudioProcessor>`

Are there any standard ways of dealing with problems like this?

Comment: The way I do this is I have an audio producer thread send samples over a channel to the thread that handles the audio device.

Comment: You should provide a [mre], including how "this code fails" (compiler output, expeted vs actual behaviour, ...).

Comment: @IvanC can you explain a little more? What kind of technique do you use to send samples? Is it still real-time safe?

Comment: @cafce25 the example is a minimal reproducible example. I have now added in the error message.

Comment: If all fields are atomic, why do you need a mutable reference?

Comment: This solves my problem. I did not realise the atomic variables do not need to be mutable to be edited.